# Is there an alternative to .showMinimized on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

When I click a button on my Python GUI it minimises the GUI window and executes a Python file on the IDLE, which is how it should be.

However, I cannot re-open the GUI window until the Python file has completely finished executing.

Is there an alternative to using .showMinimized where I can still open the GUI window anytime?

I have included the relevant part of the code below:

```
def OpenClickBSTest(self):
    SortAlgorithms.showMinimized()
    BubbleSortTest.FunctionBSTest()
```

Comment: the problem comes more from your function/script that should be executed in a thread.

Comment: @SyedElec Hi, sorry I am new to Python. How can I rectify this?

Comment: you can use QThread, here is a simple website that explains how to do this : https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/ (section Basic QThread Structure). Just reproduce the example with your own function and start your thread in `OpenClickBSTest`.